# How to cross wires in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am using Illustrator CC 2018, trying to do the same explained in [this tutorial](https://www.technicalcommunicationcenter.com/2013/03/11/how-to-cross-wires-with-adobe-illustrator-cs6/).

[image]

In the step 3, I don't see the intersection label between the circle and the segment (but they do intersect, I don't know why).

That prevents me from deleting the inner part of the rect segment.

In any case, is there any quicker way to do this? I have like 100 wire intersections and going one by one can take a long time.

Comment: Do you have Smart Guides switched on?

Comment: I have just checked it and yes, Smart Guides is on

Comment: Make sure to check: Preferences > SmartGuides > Anchor/path labels. Now select the paths with Direct Selection Toll and it will show you the label.

Comment: Sometimes if things are on very different layers illustratir does not snap stuff unless you hold ctrl down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a slightly easier method.

1. Make sure Smart Guides are on. Click and drag the circle onto the line, so that the centre of the circle intersects with the lines
2. Select both the line and the circle, by holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> as you click on them with the Selection Tool (V).
3. Choose the Shaper Tool, draw a squiggly line over the lines you wish to delete
4. Click *Object > Expand*, OK, *Object > Ungroup* (do this twice). Then click *Object > Path > Join*

I made a very quick video of the process [here](https://youtu.be/jQ5fB3ijV6g)

***Update:***

Using Shortcuts could make this quicker:

- Ungroup = <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>
- Join = <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>

You could even record step 4 as an Action to speed things up.

[image]

Comment: Seems to me that there is many unnessesery steps here. You can do all of this with the direct select tool (A), delete key and join (ctrl + j)

Comment: @joojaa I think that is what the OP has been trying to do in the tutorial  - and it's fiddly in comparison to just using the Shaper Tool.

Comment: I dont think its fiddly. But uf you want to do this fast then you can just use suitable arrowheads.

Comment: I agree @joojaa. After using the shape tool holding alt to subtract the segments, just use join (ctrl + J).

Comment: @LeoNass shortcuts will definitely speed it up, plus step 4 could be recorded as an Action.

Comment: @joojaa - you should write that as an answer, using arrowheads.

Comment: @BillyKerr Too much overhead, i mean i do have this arrowhead but you dont. So i would need to explain how to make a new arrowhead etc. Anyway i dontr have time on a irplane soon.

Comment: Maybe because I have things in different layers, selecting and removing with A the rect segments inside the circle is not working for me. @BillyKerr your solution, however, is working fine.

Comment: @DanielViaño chack that you have not hidden the control points? Anyway, you dont need the ungroups. Also like is said hold control down when snapping with the A tool and remeber to drag from circle center!

Comment: @joojaa - it's true that ungroups are not necessary to join after expanding, but then you would end up with two unnecessary groups if you used the Shaper Tool, and expanded it. Illustrator seems to love to put things in groups within groups when they really don't need to be.

Comment: @joojaa - of course LeoNass's suggestion to use the Shape Tool (as opposed to the Shaper Tool) while holding down Alt, will also work, without making any extra groups at all.

Comment: @BillyKerr shape builder is usually better no need for groups. Seem to me that shaper is just one of those adobe quality upgrades thats good onb paper but not really in fleshed out

Comment: The only problem I have with this solution is that arrowheads dissapear from the lines after applying it, and they become disabled in stroke menu

Comment: @DanielViaño - you could try Expanding your lines with arrow heads to shapes before you start. Of course that will bake the arrow heads into a shape, it will no longer be part of the stroke.

Answer (score 13):

I've never been a fan of the "delete this.. then line it up" method. I much prefer creating objects that can be intersected or combined without any manual alignment needed. You don't need any smart guides here....

[image]

1. Align circle and line
2. Use the **Shape Builder Tool** and while depressing the
   <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key, click-drag across the bottom of the
   circle.
3. Use the **Direct Selection Tool** (white arrow) to click drag and
   select the line inside the remaining circle
4. Hit the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key
5. Still with the Direct Selection Tool, click-drag to select the anchors at one of the corners
6. Choose `Object > Path > Join` or hit <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Option/Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> for "average and Join"...
7. Select the other corner's anchors and hit
   <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Option/Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>
   again.

Done.

Answer (score 8):

## Fast and Lazy method

Please go with [scott's answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/106763/104169) if you want something consistent but I'm going to share a lazy method that's a bit less accurate.

This is all done with the curvature tool. **You have to double click on the points** though to make it bend like I'm showing.

[image]

EDIT: With this tool it's actually easier to be more accurate in the latest version of Illustrator. The tool will snap to a center line making it a lot easier to line up. The only thing you have to eyball is the distance. It has issues but if you have to do this quick and it doesn't have to be 100% perfect than this is for you. NOTE: Making guides could help with this too.

How fast is it? Well here's an example where you can see the snapping effect.

[image]

More accurate but a little more slow?
Okay try this method with a guide.
[image]

Comment: How fast? How ugly ... All of them have a different size. Not what you want in electronic schematics.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Is that a rhetorical question? It's plainly stated to go with scott's answer if you want accuracy. If you absolutely needed to rush then this is perfect for personal use. It conveys the message of a crossed wire just fine.

Comment: You also say "easier to be more accurate in the latest version", but the result below that paragraph is still not convincing.

Comment: @ThomasWeller compare the two gifs. You can see the center dot is snapping to the center of the of the line. The previous version of illustrator did not have this feature. Therefore it's more accurate than the older version of Illustrator.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I've updated to show the guides I mentioned earlier.